# Pythonian way of ending while loops

Tags: python

I was wondering which of the following two ways to end a while loop is more pythonian? 
I can definitely see arguments for both ways and if I need to break in the middle of my looped code the first alternative is definitely the way to go as I dont have to execute the rest of the code.

So this thought experiment is based solely on the scenario that I want to end the loop at its actual end.

1)

```
while True:
    # do something
    if work_done:
         break
```

2)

```
a = True
while a:
    # do something
    if work_done:
         a = False
```

Comment: 1 should be faster as it avoids additional unnecessary assignment

Comment: 2) is like ... reaching over my head with my right arm to touch my left ear... I have never seen something like this.

Comment: @VineethSai `%timeit a = True. 22 ns ± 4.06 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)` incurred only twice. 44ns is nothing.

Comment: @roganjosh oh. Thanks for the insight! :)

Comment: I  think his question is about the style and not efficiency -even if the difference is practically zero -. I find the -1- more readable.

Comment: 1) is the traditional way of writing a C-style "do-while" loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would prefer the first one, as it is more pythonic and is clearer to read. The second case might be useful is later on you are using/checking the `a` variable, so its state influences code later on then I would use it otherwise the first method.

Comment: And even if you need to initialize flag for later use, it will be more readable to amend option 1 to set the flag and then break out of the loop

Answer (score -1):

> I want to end the loop at its actual end

Then:

```
while not work_done:
    # do something
```

Comment: This directly mean, you want to stick with #2.